# Change title of an element via 'onclick' event using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the code below in the `head` section of my web app:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu_s").click(function(){
            $("upt").replaceWith(function(n){
                return "<h2>Αρχικά Πιάτα</h2>";
            });
        });
        $("#menu_md").click(function(){
            $("upt").replaceWith(function(n){
                return "<h2>Κυρίως Πιάτα</h2>";
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the code below (just part of it-the necessary one :)) in the `body` section:

```
<section>
    <header>
        <upt><h2>Φαγητά & Ποτά</h2></upt>
        <h3>FoodBall Admin</h3>
    </header>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="ca-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#starters" id="menu_s">
                    <span class="ca-icon">&#59;</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Αρχικά Πιάτα</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#main_dishes" id="menu_md">
                    <span class="ca-icon">&#59;</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Κυρίως Πιάτα</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

When I click on any of the two `href` links the title **updates** successfully. However, when I click a **second** time, **nothing** happens.

Any advice will be really helpful as I am stuck for a while on this.

Comment: What is 'upt', looks like you are selecting 'upt' tag.

Comment: what is `$("upt")`

Comment: custom html5 element tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the entire `upt` element, you could just replace the inner HTML, like the code below:

```
$("upt h2").html("Κυρίως Πιάτα");
```

When you replace the `upt` tag with the returned element of the function (i.e. `<h2>...</h2>`) you are basically removing the `upt` element from the DOM.

The first time it works (because the element is there, in the DOM) but after the first click, it gets replaced by `h2` (and it's no longer there to select it for the second click)

See running demo below

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu_s").click(function() {
     $("upt h2").html("Αρχικά Πιάτα");
   });

   $("#menu_md").click(function() {
     $("upt h2").html("Κυρίως Πιάτα");
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <header>
    <upt>
      <h2>Φαγητά & Ποτά</h2>
    </upt>
    <h3>FoodBall Admin</h3>
  </header>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul class="ca-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#starters" id="menu_s">
          <span class="ca-icon">&#59;</span>
          <div class="ca-content">
            <h2 class="ca-main">Αρχικά Πιάτα</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#main_dishes" id="menu_md">
          <span class="ca-icon">&#59;</span>
          <div class="ca-content">
            <h2 class="ca-main">Κυρίως Πιάτα</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cheers friend. Tried your code it works perfectly. Thank yoy

Comment: @A.A.PEACE glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

The first time around it works because there is a upt tag, but the second time doesn't work because you replaced it with a h2 tag. you need to replace with the h2 inside a upt tag like this:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_s").click(function(){
        $("upt").replaceWith(function(n){
            return "<upt><h2>Αρχικά Πιάτα</h2></upt>";
        });
    });
    $("#menu_md").click(function(){
        $("upt").replaceWith(function(n){
            return "<upt><h2>Κυρίως Πιάτα</h2></upt>";
        });
    });
});
```

Now the second time the upt tag will be there. Hope this helps.

Comment: i understand your explanation and it is logical. however when i do it in practice it is not working not even the first time.

Comment: I left the text in both replacements the same, my bad. I edited the answer now it should work